# react-native: How to hide bottom tabbar onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to `hide bottomTabbar` when I onPress a botton.

In my App.js file I have my `ButtomTabNavigator` :

```
const ButtomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    screenOne: {
      screen: RealReviewMain,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarVisible: true,
      })
    },
    screenTwo: {
      screen: RealReviewMain,
//Here I set the tabbarVisible to true
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarVisible: true,
      })
    },
  },
)
```

From ScreenTwo, I try to `hide bottom tabbar` using `onPress`

```
<TouchableOpacity
          onPress={()=> {
            this.props.navigation.setParams({ tabBarVisible: false });
          }}/>
```

Is this the right way to do it? nothing happens.

Any advice or comment would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to hide/show a tabBar based off button press. Using `static navigationOptions`. An example would be:

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {tabBarVisible: navigation.state.params.tabBarVisible}
}
```

This is a simple example, you would need to initialize tabBarVisible since it would be false. A full component could look like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native'

class Screen extends Component {

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ tabBarVisible: true }) //initialize the state
    }

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

        return {tabBarVisible:navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.tabBarVisible}
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>           
                <Button title={"hide"} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.setParams({tabBarVisible:false})}/>
                <Button title={"show"} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.setParams({tabBarVisible:true})}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


export default Screen
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you cannot hide navigation elements once they are rendered in the page.
But, as stated [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-tab-navigator-contains-a-stack-and-you-want-to-hide-the-tab-bar-on-specific-screens) you can hide navigation elements in specific screens as follows:

```
const FeedStack = createStackNavigator({
    FeedHome: FeedScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
});

FeedStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    let tabBarVisible = true;
    if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
        tabBarVisible = false;
    }

    return {
        tabBarVisible,
    };
};
```

If you want to hide the navigator in a specific screen you can add an if condition:

```
if (navigation.state.index > 0 && navigation.state.routes[1].routeName === "<name of the screen>")
```